# In UserGroupInformation the method reloginfromkeytab not working by zookeeper login class

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos, apache-zookeeper, jaas

i am able to use hbasetemplate (spring) to connect hbase thru zookeeper with keytab, but TGT is only good for 10 hours, so using jaas to enable zookeeper login to get new TGT before old one expires, we can get the new TGT, but not able to access hbase by the new TGT, besides, this client is running on window with jdk 1.8.

is apache.zoopkeeper.login the correct way to relogin with new TGT? if so, what am I missing? if not the right way, can we get the option to resolve this issue? greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

is you issue resolved? i think first it needs to be check whether the flag returned session states the ticket to be renewable or not?

Regards
Mukesh